# android studio emulator can't play the video

Tags: java, android, video

I am using Android Studio 1.5.2 (latest stable) as part of The Complete Android Developer's Course and I am running to the error "Can't play the video" when attempting to run an app in the emulator that plays a video file. The file is an MP4 and has been placed in the res/raw folder structure within the project. I can hear the audio, but the media controls don't work and after clearing the error message, the screen remains black.

Here is the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.demo_video);
    MediaController myMediaController = new MediaController(this);

    myMediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(myMediaController);

    videoView.start();
}
```

Comment: Share logcat error.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
  VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
MediaController myMediaController = new MediaController(this);

    myMediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(myMediaController);
    String uriPath = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/"+ "demo_video";
    Uri UrlPath=Uri.parse(uriPath);
videoView.setVideoURI(UrlPath);
```